# SSE: reciprocal if not zero

Tags: c, normalization, sse

How can I take the reciprocal (inverse) of floats with SSE instructions, but **only for non-zero** values?

*Background bellow:*

I want to normalize an array of vectors so that each dimension has the same average. In C this can be coded as:

```
float vectors[num * dim]; // input data

// step 1. compute the sum on each dimension
float norm[dim];
memset(norm, 0, dim * sizeof(float));
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) for(int j = 0; j < dims; j++)
    norm[j] += vectors[i * dims + j];
// step 2. convert sums to reciprocal of average
for(int j = 0; j < dims; j++) if(norm[j]) norm[j] = float(num) / norm[j];
// step 3. normalize the data
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) for(int j = 0; j < dims; j++)
    vectors[i * dims + j] *= norm[j];
```

Now for performance reasons, I want to do this using SSE intinsics. Setp 1 et step 3 are easy, but I'm stuck at step 2. I don't seem to find any code sample or obvious SSE instruction to take the recirpocal of a value **if** it is not zero.
For the division, _mm_rcp_ps does the trick, and maybe combine it with a conditional move, but how to get a mask indicating which component is zero?

I don't need the code to the algorithm described above, just the "inverse if not zero" function:

```
__m128 rcp_nz_ps(__m128 input) {
    // ????
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
__m128 rcp_nz_ps(__m128 input) {
    __m128 mask = _mm_cmpeq_ps(_mm_set1_ps(0.0), input);
    __m128 recip = _mm_rcp_ps(input);
    return _mm_andnot_ps(mask, recip);
}
```

Each lane of `mask` is set to either `b111...11` if the input is zero, and `b000...00` otherwise.  And-not with that mask replaces elements of the reciprocal corresponding to a zero input with zero.

Comment: Damn, that was fast. I was working on my own and you beat me to it. +1

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to "test" instead of "compare", and avoid using a register set to null? Just wondering...

Comment: Besides on the last line, there's a typo: input should be recip.

Comment: @Antoine: The register set to zero doesn't actually cost you anything, typically.  Any decent compiler will simply emit `xorps`, which is recognized by the processor as a zeroing idiom and is extremely efficient (on *very* recent processors it actually doesn't even need to execute).

Comment: Unlike what the name implies, andnot(a,b) is not (a & ~b) but (~a & b).