# Efficient way to convert from premultiplied float RGBA to 8-bit RGBA?

Tags: c++, c

I'm looking for a more efficient way to convert from RGBA stored as doubles in *premultiplied colorspace* to 8-bit integer/channel RGBA *non-premulitplied colorspace*. It's a significant cost in my image processing.

For one channel, say R, the code looks something like this:

```
double temp = alpha > 0 ? src_r / alpha : 0
uint8_t out_r = (uint8_t)min( 255, max( 0, int(temp * 255 + 0.5) ) )
```

This involves three conditionals which I think prevent the compiler/CPU from optimizing this as well as it could. I think that some chips, in particular x86_64 have specialized double clamping operations, so in theory the above might be doable without conditionals.

Is there some technique, or special functions, which can make this conversion faster?

*I'm using GCC and would be happy with a solution in C or C++ or with inline ASM if need be.*

Comment: have you already tried the `-ffast-math` flag ? Be careful that this flag can possibly change the behaviour of your program, test your program after compilation.

Comment: Why are you storing alpha like that? Normally people use a number from 0 to 1 and multiply rather than divide.

Comment: @n.m. This is the way to convert from premultiplied space back to non-premultiplied space. I don't know a method that doesn't require division.  Note: All my double values have a normal range from 0.0 through 1.0, but a few may lay outside that range (thus the clamping).

Comment: @user2485710, -ffast-math doesn't change my timings. I am compiling at -O3.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: `n / x = n * (1 / x)`. Get rid of that branch and store alpha values in the range of `0..1.0`

Comment: also note that `-O3` sometimes backfires in terms of performances, http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1622 and you should always compare multiple configurations during the compilation and testing phase; for example it's always nice to compare `-O3`, `-O2` and `-Os` as a start. For additional informations about floating point optimizations, at least from the `gcc` standpoint, here is a link for you http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath

Comment: @user2485710, just checked and -O2 and -O3 are the same speed, -Os is significantly slower.

Comment: @EdS. My stored alpha is in the normal range of 0..1. To convert out of premultiplied space requires the division -- unless you know of another approach.

Comment: than there is `-Ofast` and all the other "sensible" flags that you can find in the page linked above. There is also another thing that you should care about: signed vs unsigned. Be careful from a numerical standpoint with what you are doing since you are converting a signed type to an unsigned one with a C-style cast.

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand this. Alpha is defined as the transparency *factor*, a number from 0 (fully opaque) to 1 (fully transparent). If you work with bytes, this translates to 0..255, but logically it's still 0..1. You are storing a reciprocal to that number, only to divide by it *and* check for zero *each time* you use it. Why?

Comment: @n.m. No, that's not what I'm doing. My alpha, and other channels, are stored as doubles from 0..1 in *premultiplied colorspace*. I am converting them into *non-premultiplied colorspace*. To get into premultiplied space requires multiplication, thus to get out requires division.

Comment: I see what you are doing. I just don't understand ehy. No reason to do that.

Comment: @n.m. I don't see that you are offering an alternative. I just want an efficient algortihm that converts from premultiplied colorspace into non-premultiplied space. The above is the only way I know how. Simply saying not to do it that way is of zero help to me.

Comment: Why not do the clamping based on the alpha value before you get into the costly division business? if `alpha <= 0` your red value is 0, if `alpha >= 1` your red channel is `src_r * 255.0 + 0.5`. If you have an image with many purely opaque or purely transparent pixels, that might speed up your calculations.

Comment: OK premultiplied means premultiplied by alpha, and you need to get the original value back.  Misunderstanding on my part, I apologize. In that case, why not store 1/alpha? You can store +infinity just fine.

Comment: Alternatively, just divide by alpha without any check for zero. If alpha is indeed zero, you will get infinity back and clamp it to 1 (or 255) in the next statement.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an outline with some code (untested).  This will convert four pixels at once.  The main advantage of this method is that it only has to do the division once (not four times).  Division is slow.  But it has to do a tranpose (AoS to SoA) to do this.  It uses mostly SSE except to convert the doubles to floats (which needs AVX).

```
1.) Load 16 doubles
2.) Convert them to floats
3.) Transpose from rgba rgba rgba rgba to rrrr gggg bbbb aaaa
4.) Divide all 4 alphas in one instruction
5.) Round floats to ints
6.) Compress 32-bit to 8-bit with saturation for underflow and overflow
7.) Transpose back to rgba rgba rgba rgba
9.) Write 4 pixels as integers in rgba format

#include <immintrin.h>
double rgba[16];
int out[4];

//load 16 doubles and convert to floats
__m128 tmp1 = _mm256_cvtpd_ps(_mm256_load_pd(&rgba[0]));
__m128 tmp2 = _mm256_cvtpd_ps(_mm256_load_pd(&rgba[4]));
__m128 tmp3 = _mm256_cvtpd_ps(_mm256_load_pd(&rgba[8]));
__m128 tmp4 = _mm256_cvtpd_ps(_mm256_load_pd(&rgba[12]));
//rgba rgba rgba rgba -> rrrr bbbb gggg aaaa
_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS(tmp1,tmp2,tmp3,tmp4);
//fact = alpha > 0 ? 255.0f/ alpha : 0
__m128 fact = _mm_div_ps(_mm_set1_ps(255.0f),tmp4); 
tmp1 = _mm_mul_ps(fact,tmp1); //rrrr
tmp2 = _mm_mul_ps(fact,tmp2); //gggg
tmp3 = _mm_mul_ps(fact,tmp3); //bbbb    
tmp4 = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_set1_ps(255.0f), tmp4); //aaaa

//round to nearest int
__m128i tmp1i = _mm_cvtps_epi32(tmp1);
__m128i tmp2i = _mm_cvtps_epi32(tmp2);
__m128i tmp3i = _mm_cvtps_epi32(tmp3);
__m128i tmp4i = _mm_cvtps_epi32(tmp4);

//compress from 32bit to 8 bit
__m128i tmp5i = _mm_packs_epi32(tmp1i, tmp2i);
__m128i tmp6i = _mm_packs_epi32(tmp3i, tmp4i);
__m128i tmp7i = _mm_packs_epi16(tmp5i, tmp6i);

//transpose back to rgba rgba rgba rgba
__m128i out16 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(in16,_mm_setr_epi8(0x0,0x04,0x08,0x0c, 0x01,0x05,0x09,0x0d, 0x02,0x06,0x0a,0x0e, 0x03,0x07,0x0b,0x0f));
_mm_store_si128((__m128i*)out, tmp7i);
```

Comment: +1 for "tiled" processing by blocks of 4, this optimizes use of SIMD

Comment: you kind of cheated though : all the computations are on floats instead of doubles. Not that I blame you, if it were up to me I'd do everything in floats ;)

Comment: @Antoine,  I think we can use floats.  It's going from double to 8-bit - that's a huge loss in precision.  You just have to assume that you start with double.  So in your code it's okay to use float but the input has to be double.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is pseudo code, but with SSE how about something like

```
const c = (1/255, 1/255, 1/255, 1/255)
floats = (r, g, b, a)
alpha =  (a, a, a, a)
alpha *= (c, c, c, c)
floats /= alpha
ints = cvt_float_to_int(floats)
ints = max(ints, (255, 255, 255, 255))
```

Here's an implementation

```
void convert(const double* floats, byte* bytes, const int width, const int height, const int step) {
    for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        const double* float_row = floats + y * width;
        byte*        byte_row  = bytes  + y * step;

        for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            __m128d src1  = _mm_load_pd(float_row);
            __m128d src2  = _mm_load_pd(float_row + 2);
            __m128d mul   = _mm_set1_pd(255.0f / float_row[3]);
            __m128d norm1 = _mm_min_pd(_mm_set1_pd(255), _mm_mul_pd(src1, mul));
            __m128d norm2 = _mm_min_pd(_mm_set1_pd(255), _mm_mul_pd(src2, mul));
            __m128i dst1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_cvtpd_epi32(norm1), _mm_set_epi8(0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,4,0));
            __m128i dst2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(_mm_cvtpd_epi32(norm2), _mm_set_epi8(0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,4,0,0x80,0x80));
            _mm_store_ss((float*)byte_row, _mm_castsi128_ps(_mm_or_si128(dst1, dst2)));

            float_row += 4;
            byte_row += 4;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit: In my original answer I worked with floats instead of double, below if anyone's interested** thanks to @Z boson for catching that - @OP: I don't handle `alhpa==0` cases, so you'll get `NaN` with my solution, if you want this handling, go with @Z boson's solution.
Here's the float version:

```
void convert(const float* floats, byte* bytes, const int width, const int height, const int step) {
    for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        const float* float_row = floats + y * width;
        byte*        byte_row  = bytes  + y * step;

        for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            __m128 src = _mm_load_ps(float_row);
            __m128 mul = _mm_set1_ps(255.0f / float_row[3]);
            __m128i cvt = _mm_cvtps_epi32(_mm_mul_ps(src, mul));
            __m128i res = _mm_min_epi32(cvt, _mm_set1_epi32(255));
            __m128i dst = _mm_shuffle_epi8(res, _mm_set_epi8(0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,0x80,12,8,4,0));
            _mm_store_ss((float*)byte_row, _mm_castsi128_ps(dst));

            float_row += 4;
            byte_row += 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Because of SSE alignments constraints, make sure your input pointers are 16-bytes aligned, and use `step` to make sure each row starts at an aligned address, many libs take such a `step` argument, but if you don't need it, you can simplify by using a single loop.

I quickly tested with this and get good values:

```
int main() {
    __declspec(align(16)) double src[] = { 10,100,1000,255, 10,100,20,50 };
    __declspec(align(16)) byte  dst[8];
    convert(src, dst, 2, 1, 16); // dst == { 10,100,255,255 }
    return 0;
}
```

I only have visual studio right now, so I can't test with gcc's optimizer, but I'm getting a **x1.8 speedup** for double and x4.5 for floats, it could be less with gcc -O3 but my code could be optimized more.

Comment: The OP said his values are doubles not floats.  What happens when you divide by zero (_mm_set1_ps(255.0f / 0);)

Comment: @Zboson: indeed, I'm so used to floats I didn't catch that... Sorry! Division by zero would result in `NaN`s, depending on the use case, it may or may not be worth it to [add a compare + mask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606483/sse-reciprocal-if-not-zero)

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I do cvt = alpha >0 ? 255.0/alpha : 0 using `_mm_blendv_ps(255.0/alpha, 0, alpha>0)`.  I don't know if it's necessary.  The main problem in my code is doing the transpose twice.  You don't do that.  You also don't compress twice.  Your code is probably better (+1).

Comment: thanks, I converted my solution to doubles, but the performance gain isn't as nice. I'm not very satisfied with the shuffle, maybe some other instructions could move the bytes around more elegantly ?

Comment: Actually, I got distracted by my own method.  I'm doing four pixels at once so we have do multiply all your instructions by four.  The main advantage of my method is that I only have to do the division once and you have to do it four times.  Also I convert 32-bit to 8-bit in three steps and you do it in 4 steps (for four pixels).  The price I pay for this is doing the transpose twice.  However, I think the last transpose can be done in one intrinsic now using `_mm_shuffle_epi8`.  So mostly it's a question of four divisions vs eight shuffles (_MM_TRANSPOSE_PS uses eight shuffles).

Comment: _mm_div_ps has a latency and throughout of 10-14 (SandyBridge) and _mm_shuffle_ps is 1 and 1.  So I think only dividing once (instead of four times) but having to do the transpose should be better.  I'll have to profile this at some point.

Comment: @Zboson: yes, doing 4 pixels at a time does less instructions per pixels and better exploit vectorization. But it means you must have quite a large margin on your data, and is arguably harder to maintain. Also, at this point don't data access take longer than computes? Maybe we could pipeline by prefetching next data during division? Also wouldn't recpiprocal+mul be faster than divide?

Comment: I was able to do the transpose back in two intrinsics (using _mm_shuffle_epi8 and _mm_setr_epi8) thanks to reading your code.  I updated my answer.  I also tested the division by zero.  It returns zero so it's not necessary to do the selection as I was doing.

Comment: Yes, `_mm_rcp_ps` would be faster but I'm leaving it as `_mm_div_ps` for now.

Answer (score 1):

Three things to look into

1. Do this with OpenGL using a shader.
2. Use Single Instruction Multiple Data (SIMD) - you might get a bit of parallelization.
3. Look at using saturated arithmetic operations (SADD and SMULL on arm)

Comment: I'll look at the saturated arithmetic. I think to some degree GCC is already doing vectorizing, and might even be doing some limited saturated math. I guess I'll find out.

Comment: +1 for using OpenGL/OpenCL, it is well suited to fast image processing